# What's the name of the place where you can exchange waste material for money?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary

What's the name of the place where you can get money for every kilo of iron, copper or aluminum you bring in? Collecting yard?

Comment: Recycling center, if it's material that you can recycle.

Answer (score 2):

I know that here in California, USA, they're called *recycling centers*. I assume this usage extends to the rest of the US.

> Californians don't have to go out of their way to recycle. There are 1,687 recycling centers statewide that buy back empty California Refund Value (CRV) beverage containers, most conveniently located near places you live and work.
>   ([Ca.gov](http://www.calrecycle.ca.gov/BevContainer/Recyclers/Directory/Default.aspx?lang=en-US))

I think they're also called *recycling centres* in the UK.

> There are recycling centres and scrap dealers all across the UK that will pay for a bundle of aluminium cans. ([thinkcans.net](http://thinkcans.net/cash-cans))

I think another name for it might be *scrapyard*, but I'm not entirely sure. I think this might be used more with cars or other bulky items. Here's one usage I found online

> Since 1949, Atlas Iron & Metal has been providing a friendly environment to cater to the needs of those who scrap. As a family business that began in the auto wrecking industry, Atlas Iron & Metal Co., has developed into one of the Los Angeles areas most dependable **scrap yards** & recycling facilities.
>
> [...] For over half a century, Atlas has opened it’s gates and catered to the needs of individuals who scrap.
>
> We buy scrap copper, steel, aluminum, stainless steel, brass, hi temp alloys such as carbide, nickel, inconel, titanium & more!
>   ([Atlas Iron & Metal Co.](http://atlasironandmetal.com/))

Comment: From a British English perspective I would definitely go for "scrapyard". To me "recycling centre" means either a) the place where I can dispose of bulky household waste for free or b) a big operation where dumptrucks turn up with waste, either council or commercially run. If I had a couple of old copper water tanks that I wanted to get paid for I'd google for a "scrapyard".

Comment: I agree with AndyT.  A recycling center is generally where you are allowed to dispose of materials, not where you can exchange them for money.  You would generally need a scrapyard, broker, or other business that purchases materials.